# Cannot set height of display:table in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to create a grid/table in CSS where each cell contains some content. However, the content on the first row is getting cut off by the content on the second row. I assume I need to increase the height of the each cell, but whenever I use the height property nothing changes. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="grid-container outline">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-0"><p>Featured</p></div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-container {

         width: 100%;
         max-width: 1200px;
         margin: 0 auto;
         border-top: 12px solid #03A3D3;
 }

 .row:before,
 .row:after {
         content:"";
         display: table ;
         clear:both;
 }


 .col-1 { 
          width: 20%;
          float: left;
          padding: 20px;

 }

 .col-1 > p {
          background-color: #03A3D3;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          text-align: center;
          color: white;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use viewport width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using display:flex for this layout

Div to have width and height as 100% body also need to have height and width as 100%,instead you can consider using viewport width and height

check this snippet

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 12px solid #03A3D3;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.row * {
  
}
.col-1 {
  width: 25vw;
 height: 30vh;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
.col-1 > p {
  background-color: #03A3D3;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container outline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-0">
      <p>Featured Featured FeaturedFeaturedFeaturedFeaturedFeaturedFeaturedFeaturedFeaturedFeaturedFeatured
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">Content Here Content HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent Here Content HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent
      HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent Here Content HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent Here</div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, works great! I think using the viewport for width and height and changing the display property was what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

We can also try like below snippet without using **display:flex**. flex will not support to old browsers.

```css
.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 12px solid #03A3D3;
}
.row:before, .row:after{
 content:"";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
.col-1 { 
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.col-1 > p {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container outline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-0">
     <p>Featured</p>
     <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
     <p>
      Content Here...<br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
   <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
    <div class="col-1">
     <p>
      Content Here...<br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">Content Here</div>
 </div>
</div>
```